# VB.NET Serialization Missing dot right before new line serialization

Tags: vb.net, serialization

I've been using XML serialization for a while, and today I realized something really odd. If I have a new line right after a "dot" (.), when i deserialize, I lose the dot. Has anyone ever had this happen to them? The following is my serialization code:

**Serialize**

```
Dim xmlSerializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StoreLicense), New System.Type() {GetType(SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StationLicense)})

        Dim gen As LicenseGenerator

        If store Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("store")
        ElseIf store.StationLicenses Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("store.StationLicenses")
        ElseIf store.StationLicenses.Length = 0 Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("store.StationLicenses", "Must contain at least one element.")
        End If

        ' Create a license generator for issuing new license keys.
        gen = New LicenseGenerator(store)

        ' Generate store key.
        store.LicenseKey = gen.GenerateLicenseKey

        ' Generate individual station keys.
        For Each station In store.StationLicenses
            station.LicenseKey = gen.GenerateLicenseKey(station)
        Next

        ' Write license to file.
        Using xFile As Xml.XmlWriter = Xml.XmlWriter.Create(licenseFile)
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(xFile, store)

            xFile.Close()
        End Using
```

**Deserialize**

```
Dim xmlDeserializer As New System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(GetType(SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StoreLicense), New System.Type() {GetType(SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StationLicense)})
        Dim result As SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StoreLicense

        Using xFile As Xml.XmlReader = Xml.XmlReader.Create(licenseFile)
            result = DirectCast(xmlDeserializer.Deserialize(xFile), SilverWare.Licensing.Common.StoreLicense)

            xFile.Close()
        End Using

        Return result
```

The really funny part is that if I have a space after the dot, or remove the new line character, there are no problems. This only happens if it is dot which I find mind boggling.

Here is a quick sample of my XML file that was created when I serialized:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<StoreLicense xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
  <ReceiptAddress>98 N. Washington St.
Berkeley Springs West Virginia</ReceiptAddress> 
  <Name>Ambrae House at Berkeley Springs</Name> 
  <AliasName>Ambrae House</AliasName> 
  <Address1>98 N. Washington St.</Address1> 
  <Address2 /> 
...
</StoreLicense>
```

The line that is having the problem is the ReceiptAddress Node.

Comment: Where is this dot and newline?

Comment: The dot and new line is in the outputted file. Basically I have an object that is serializable. This object contains a bunch of strings, and one of those strings contains something like:

234 Gor St.
Toronto, Ontario

Notice the dot after st. That will disappear when I deserialize. When I look at the outputted xml file, the dot and new line look fine. It's only during the deserialization that I lose the dot.

Comment: @Mattias is right.  Can you give us a quick sample input and output, please?

Comment: If you guys mean the XML file, here it is.

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<StoreLicense xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
...
  <ReceiptAddress>98 N. Washington St.
Berkeley Springs West Virginia</ReceiptAddress> 
  <Name>Ambrae House at Berkeley Springs</Name> 
  <AliasName>Ambrae House</AliasName> 
  <Address1>98 N. Washington St.</Address1> 
  <Address2 /> 
...
</StoreLicense>

Comment: Sorry about the messy post above. I'm still getting used to stackoverflow.

Anyways, I've added it to the question.

Comment: I see. I haven't tried to repro, but surely the issue (if there is one) must be with the XML serializer and not with the VB language/compiler. I'd expect the exact same behavior if you rewrote the code in, say, C#. So the subject "VB.NET missing..." is kinda misleading.

Comment: I tried to change the title. I'm never good with titles, and I'm sorry if it was misleading. I've ran into bugs that are only on VB vs C#, so I wanted people to know that I am using VB.NET incase someone knew something weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I was using someone elses dll, I didn't even think that it would be modifying my data when we imported it. What was happening was that the other programmer had a reg_ex that was looking for a dot before a new line. That was my issue, and my grief for 3 months.

Answer (score 0):

This post on MSDN seems to answer your question.

[MSDN: Serialize String containing only whitespace such as a " " character](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/1e09e005-c8f1-4b86-a02f-dbf2b062b68a/)

From that post, try this:

```
<XmlAttribute("xml:space")> _
Public SpacePreserve As [String] = "preserve"
```

This creates a root node like the following:

```
<DataImportBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xml:space="preserve">
```

Jim

Comment: Hey Jim, thanks for the response. Unfortunately this did not solve my issue. I do have data between the node, so it's not white space being removed.